# AWS SNS response handling

Tags: java, amazon-sns

Am new to implement AWS SNS SMS gateway for my Java program. After the successful publishing message to AWS, I would like to know is the message send or not? Its always giving a response with messageId even the message fails to send. Is there any specific method or API to expose for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [SNS FAQ](https://aws.amazon.com/sns/faqs/):

> Q: How do I track the delivery status of my SMS messages?
>
> By enabling the Delivery Status feature in Amazon SNS, you can get information on the following for each message: MessageID, Time Sent, Destination Phone Number, Disposition, Disposition Reason (if applicable), Price, and Dwell Time.

In other words from the docs:

> Amazon Simple Notification Service (Amazon SNS) provides support to log the delivery status of push notification messages. After you configure application attributes, log entries will be sent to CloudWatch Logs for messages sent from Amazon SNS to mobile endpoints. Logging message delivery status helps provide better operational insight, such as the following:
>   * Know whether a push notification message was delivered from Amazon SNS to the push notification service.
>   * Identify the response sent from the push notification service to Amazon SNS.
>   * Determine the message dwell time (the time between the publish timestamp and just before handing off to a push notification service).

Reference, check for code examples:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-msg-status.html

So it seems you're up to using cloudwatch for this. The messageid you get from the API will of course be useful to filter for the information.

I suggest that you open a ticket for AWS support (because of your further questions as comments):
For professional support I suggest to open a case with them: https://console.aws.amazon.com/support/home#/case/create?issueType=service-limit-increase&limitType=service-code-sns-text-messaging

Comment: Hi thanks for the quick response. I already went through this. But I would like to know that, is any other method for the same. If anything is available, please help me dude.
Also I would like to know that, If am sending monthly limit to aws, then it will be the monthly limit for a me. If am not sending limit then the aws will set the limit for me. Is there any way to make the limit as unlimited on SNS SMS sending? Please help bro if there

Comment: This is the only way I'm aware of, but that we can hope that someone will pop in to correct it. As for the limits: I personally doubt that you can go "unlimited". I think that AWS needs these limits for two reasons: 1. your monthly spending limit ensures that you're not going off the rails by mistake, which would mean a potential customer satisfactory issue 2. they also need to provision infrastructure according to the configured limits. Sorry for the limited help I can give.

Comment: In case the answer (really) helped you, feel free to indicate that with an upvote.

Comment: I have one more query about the SNS gateway, The attribute which we have setting as "maxPrice" in the initialization, is the max price for the customer on a month or maxPrice for each SMS? Could you please give me a brief description of this. I got confused on the aws point of way